# Python __super black magic failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, metaclass, descriptor

I want to add an attribute for every class created by a metaclass. For example, when a class named `C` is created, I want add an attribute `C._C__sup` whose value is the descriptor `super(C)`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict): # Not overriding type.__new__
        cls.__dict__['_' + name + '__sup'] = super(cls)
        # Not calling type.__init__; do I need it?

class C(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

c = C()
print c._C__sup
```

This gives me:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    'dictproxy' object does not support item assignment
```

---

Some background information:
<sub>(You don't have to read this part)</sub>

Inspired by [this article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236278), what I'm doing is trying to avoid "hardcoding" the class name when using `super`:

> The idea there is to use the unbound super objects as private
>   attributes. For instance, in our example, we could define the private
>   attribute `__sup` in the class `C` as the unbound super object
>   `super(C)`:
>
> ```
> >>> C._C__sup = super(C)
> ```
>
> With this definition inside the methods the syntax `self.__sup.meth`
>   can be used as an alternative to `super(C, self).meth`. The advantage
>   is that you avoid to repeat the name of the class in the calling
>   syntax, since that name is hidden in the mangling mechanism of private
>   names. **The creation of the `__sup` attributes can be hidden in a
>   metaclass and made automatic.** So, all this seems to work: but
>   actually this not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setattr` instead of assignment to `cls.__dict__`:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict): # Not overriding type.__new__
        setattr(cls, '_' + name + '__sup', super(cls))
        super(Meta, cls).__init__(name, bases, clsdict)

class C(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    def say(self):
        return 'wow'

class D(C):
    def say(self):
        return 'bow' + self.__sup.say()

c = C()
print(c._C__sup)
# <super: <class 'C'>, <C object>>
d = D()
print(d.say())
```

prints

```
bowwow
```

---

By the way, it is a good idea to call

```
        super(Meta, cls).__init__(name, bases, clsdict)
```

inside `Meta.__init__` to allow `Meta` to participate in class hierarchies which
might need `super` to properly call a chain of `__init__`s. This seems
particularly appropriate since you are building a metaclass to assist with the
use of `super`.